# Converting local time into UTC time in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using var

```
date= new Date();
```

in my controller to get current local time.
I am getting the output like this-

```
var date=Mon Aug 03 2015 07:56:55 GMT +0530(India Standard Time)
```

but i need UTC time.
How to get UTC time in **angularjs** or convert local time into **UTC** time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date=new Date();    //will give local time
var date1=date..toUTCString();      //will give
```

Answer (score 0):

use `date.toISOString()`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

using `moment.js` you can convert the local date to `UTC` date easily.

**Syntax**

```
moment.utc(Date);
```

[Moment DOCS](http://momentjs.com/docs/)